# how to Import IMG dynamically in Vite

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, vite

How can dynamic imports in Vite.js be used to improve code organization and loading performance when dealing with a large number of assets like images?

```
`// ASSETS
import Github from '../../assets/github.png'
import Instagram from '../../assets/instagram.png'
import Linkin from '../../assets/linkin.png'
import Twitter from '../../assets/twitter.png'
import Line from '../../assets/Line.png'
import OwnerImg from '../../assets/OwnerImg.png'

import Css from '../../assets/tech/css.png'
import Gh1 from '../../assets/tech/github1.png'
import html from '../../assets/tech/html.png'
import Js from '../../assets/tech/javascript.png'
import Rjs from '../../assets/tech/reactjs.png'
import tcss from '../../assets/tech/tcss.png'
`
```

Comment: do you mean something [like this](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/import#importing_modules_with_a_non-literal_specifier)?

Comment: like creating a index.jsx where all of the img assets imports are present and then import it to main something like that. T.T

Comment: and then use it like this `<img src= { example.png } />`

Comment: You can use a [glob Import](https://vitejs.dev/guide/features.html#glob-import)

Comment: Wow Thanks budds! @Reyno